# Arduino, C, Linker error, ESP32 target

Tags: arduino, linker, linker-errors, esp32

I use Arduino IDE to develop code for ESP8266 and ESP32 (that in fact doesn't matter, it's only the toolchain that's different than classic Arduino for Atmel AVRs).

I've had a code that worked, had no build errors or warnings. The project included custom .c/.h files for OneWire, DS18B20 etc.

All okay. Then I added new, custom .c/.h sources, include it in main.ino but get a linker error:

```
sketch\my_esp32.ino.cpp.o:(.literal._Z14Equalizer_Initv+0x18): undefined reference to `init_3band_state(EQSTATE*, int, int, int)'
sketch\my_esp32.ino.cpp.o: In function `Equalizer_Init()'
```

Everything is included and I can browse symbols though.. When I use the VisualMicro addon for VisualStudio, it does the same, but shows verbose output that says it has built sources, but failed after **Linking it all together...**

The problem is in dsp.h/dsp.c

Simplified sources:

my_esp32.ino

```
#include "dsp.h"

EQSTATE *equalizer;

void Equalizer_Init()
{
    init_3band_state(equalizer, 800, 5000, 50000);
}

void setup()
{
    Equalizer_Init();
}

void loop()
{

}
```

dsp.h

```
typedef struct
{
    //some variables here...
}EQSTATE;

void   init_3band_state(EQSTATE* es, int lowfreq, int highfreq, int mixfreq);
```

dsp.c

```
#include "dsp.h"

void init_3band_state(EQSTATE* es, int lowfreq, int highfreq, int mixfreq)
{
    //some simple code
}
```

In output it even says `my_esp32.ino:384: undefined reference to init_3band_state(EQSTATE*, int, int, int)`
but on the line 384
 is not code related to this dsp at all..
If I comment out the call to init_3band_state, it will build again.

I'll appreciate any help

Comment: Arduino is not C! You likely have a C++ name-mangling problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there was missing

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// code...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

in my .h source, maybe one day it'll help to someone with similar problem.